# Android Facebook SDK integration

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I want to integrate facebook api in android.
I had implemented facebook 2.0 earlier I want to know if facebook sdk 2.0 is deprecated or not because I want to use 2.0 instead of facebook sdk 3.0 due to time limitation.

I have to fetch friend list, wall post fetch friends info eg :-email,profile pic,
please advice.

Comment: v2 is deprecated now. Still you can use that but advisable to use v3 so that in future no change is required.